# Impossible to invoke a method on a null variable

Tags: templating, assets, error-message

I call a asset like this:

```
{% set headImage = entry.geschaeftsbereichHeadImage.first() %}
<img src="{{ headImage.url(headBanner) }}"
```

If I don't ad any image to this field there is a twig error:

> Impossible to invoke a method ("url") on a null variable

When I don't ad any Image to this field in the CP shouldn't there be just no image? Why the error? If I ad a image it works just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the [`first`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#first) method *only tries* to get an asset model. But if there's no asset added to the field it simply returns `null`. So calling a method like `getUrl`, or accessing a property like `url` or `title` can't work, as they do not exist for `null`.

```
{% set image = entry.geschaeftsbereichHeadImage.first() %}

{% if image %}
    <img src="{{ image.url(headBanner) }}">
{% endif %}
```

Or if you'd like to display a fallback image consider somthing like this:

```
{% set image = entry.geschaeftsbereichHeadImage.first() %}
{% set imageUrl = image ? image.url(headBanner) : 'path/to/fallback.jpg' %}

<img src="{{ imageUrl }}">
```