# Images in Matrix field

Tags: templating, assets, matrix

First time working with Craft. I've got a Matrix field for team member profiles, title, name, image, etc.

I've got all the info pulled into the page but can't get the image. Here is my code, any help is appreciated!

```
{% for block in entry.teamMember %} 
    <figure class="team-item">
        <img src="{{ memberPhoto.url }}" alt="{{ block.memberName }}" />

        <figcaption class="team-item--info">
            <h3>{{ block.memberName }}</h3>
            <h4>{{ block.memberTitle }}</h4>
            <h5>hometown: {{ block.memberLocation }}</h5>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the assets as follows:

```
{% for asset in block.memberPhoto %}
    <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="{{ block.memberName }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

See https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields for more info.

Comment: Instead of a loop it's way better for your page performance to use the `first` method to get the first asset. Only use a loop if there's multiple images.

Comment: Also see http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13401/impossible-to-invoke-a-method-on-a-null-variable

Comment: Ok great, Either one works. So I guess I will go with the first method for performance because there is only one photo per profile. Thanks!